# change div z-index from high to low if div crosses over other div when window resized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width, z-index

i have a div called 'start-button' with a higher z-index than an image on my page.

Basically if a user shrinks the window width to anything lower than 1024x768 then i want the z-index of 'start-button' to be set below the image so that the image then appears on top of the other div.

is there a way of using jquery of css to say that if the window width goes lower than 1024x768 then to change the z-index of the divs? or can i use something like css .start-button:width=37.7%{ to determine when the divs z-index should change.

```
<div  class="start-button"></div>
<div class="image"></div>
```

css for start-button:

```
.start-button{

    border: 1px solid #3f3f3f;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: #434343;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
     font-family: "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #444444;
    text-align:center;
    width: 90px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:150;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:400;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background-color:#333333;

    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #9f9f9f 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #9f9f9f 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #9f9f9f 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #9f9f9f 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #9f9f9f 100%);
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

image css:

```
.header_logo_place{
    width:100%;
    height:525px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:4%;
    background-image:url(../img/image_logo2013.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:bottom left;
        position:relative;
        margin-top:-1px;
        z-index:230;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS media-queries for this, no need for javascript/jQuery:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 768px) {
    .start-button {
        z-index: 0; /* amend as required */
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but don't you need 'screen and' after @media? I've always seen it that way.

Comment: @fred02138 only if you specifically want to target `screen` media. The one above is a catch all which will also work on `print` and other media types. I'll leave that to the OP to amend as needed.

Comment: do u know if this works in chrome as it doesn't seem to be working for me?

Comment: ooops nevermind i got it working, made a typo, thanks